# How can I delete a file served by a custom controller after it has been downloaded?

Tags: files, 9, page-controller

Starting from [How do I create a file download URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253636/how-do-i-create-a-file-download-url)
I've build a custom controller that allows users to download a PDF file.

#### my_module.routing.yml

```yaml
my_module.pdf_link:
  path: '/my-module/pdf/download'
  defaults:
    _title: 'PDF download'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::downloadPDF'
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
```

#### MyModuleController

```php
public function downloadPDF() {
  $pdf_stream = $this->restCallThatReturnAPdfStream();

  $headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="download.pdf"'
  ];

  $temporary_pdf_file = $this->fileSystem->saveData($pdf_stream, 'temporary://mytempfile.pdf', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE); 

  return new BinaryFileResponse($temporary_pdf_file, 200, $headers, TRUE);
}
```

This file must be private per user, so other users shouldn't be able to download it.

I think I could delete the file after the controller returns the response, instead of implementing some complex access control check for the file, but I've no clue how I can easily do.

For example, I could set a Cron queue to delete those files every N minutes, but it seems an overkill.

I cannot also change when temporary files are deleted because those files are used elsewhere in the site and I wouldn't risk to break some other existing logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`BinaryFileResponse::deleteFileAfterSend`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/function/BinaryFileResponse%3A%3AdeleteFileAfterSend/9.2.x):

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($temporary_pdf_file, 200, $headers, TRUE);
return $response->deleteFileAfterSend(TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was right under my nose but I could find it xD